# How do I attribute adjectives to a brush?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

Simple question - say I have a paint brush and I want to state the color that the brush will use for painting, do I say

> The brush's color is red

or

> The brushes color is red

My reasoning is:

> Brush = singular (I have a brush)
>
> Brushes = plural (I have many brushes)
>
> Brush's = a property of the brush (the Brush's color is red)

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct - The brush's color is red.

Comment: It's better to say "the brush is red or the color of the brush is red.

Comment: Or just "That's the red brush"

Answer (score 1):

Whoa! You are asking *"...the color that the brush **will use** for painting"* means that that brush is using 'red color' to paint a wall or whatever.

So, what you are saying here is **actually** this -

[image: A black brush to paint red]

But then, in the title, you ask the color that *belongs to the brush*. In other words, the color of the brush itself.

If you mean this...

[image: Red brush]

It's a ***red brush.***

Answer (score 0):

When you dip the brush in red paint, it has red paint on it. But this is not the "brush's color"; it's just the *paint's*  color.